# Where does control return to after onPostExecute() method of AsynchTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsynchTask which is called from with in a function in my MainActivity. 
After the onPostExecute method is executed ,the control doesn't seem to return to the function where I called the AsynchTask.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<AsynchInput,Void,AsynchOutput>{

    protected AsynchOutput doInBackground(AsynchInput... placesURL) {

        ...
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(AsynchOutput result) {
     ....
    }


}


public void showInterestingPlacesNearby(GoogleMap myMap,Location loc){

    ....
    ...

    new GetPlaces().execute(new AsynchInput(myMap,placesSearchStr));


}
```

}

The code I write after the new new GetPlaces().execute doesn't execute. How do I continue after the AysnchTask returns.

edit: I used the AsynchTask as an inner class for my MainActivity.

Comment: Buddy `AsyncTask` is the background thread, which is ofcourse a separate thread; different that the main UI thread. So, ideally it should come there. What piece of code you have there? Also where are you calling the execute() function? In onCreate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is used to run code on the background thread *from* the UI thread. This does not behave like a function call, and execution continues **immediately** with the statement following the `.execute()` call. At the same time, the code in `doInBackground` of your AsyncTask is executed on the background thread and runs without blocking the UI thread. This is the intended behaviour, and without it using `AsyncTask` would be pointless.

The only way to respond to the end of the async operation is to do that within `onPostExecute` - you can also take action within `onProgressUpdate` if you need to take some action in response to your background code.

So your `showInterestingPlacesNearby()` method does not need to do anything after the `.execute` call - the code you want to execute there should probably go into `onPostExecute`.

Alternatively, you could use `onProgressUpdate` to process items as they are found, instead of waiting for the entire async operation to complete before showing everything at once. For this you need to use `publishProgress` in your `doInBackground` whenever something is found.

Comment: Thanks.. I realized after reading this that what I wrote after execute is indeed executing. It's supposed to show places on the map. But since the places list is empty (before doInBackground completes execution), it is not showing any places on the map!

Comment: No problem...sometimes just asking the question leads you to the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

a possibile solution could be:
take the codes you entered after .execute and put that in a private method

```
private void AfterTask() {
//your code written after .execute here
}
```

in the onPostExecute, just call that method

```
protected void onPostExecute(AsynchOutput result) {
    AfterTask();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myTask.execute("url");
String result = "";
try {
      result = myTask.get().toString();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
}catch (ExecutionException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```